# CopyToDataTable is not a member of system.array

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a function in a VB.Net script file, but it produces the error 'CopyToDataTable' is not a member of 'system.array'. Any ideas?

```
Public Function CollectionFromTable(tableName As String, sql As String, sortOrder As String) As DataTable
    Dim foundRows() As DataRow
    foundRows = ds.Tables(tableName).Select(sql, sortOrder)

    Return foundRows.CopyToDataTable
End Function
```

Note: I have the following imports at the top but still get the error.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data.DataRow
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Collections
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [extension method in the `DataTableExtensions` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx). You need to have a reference to the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`. (You've already got an import for the right namespace.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx) (`CopyToDataTable` from `DataTableExtensions`), it's in `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`. Do you have that assembly referenced in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in VS2010 and now it is solved by adding the above reference. To add the ref. in VS2010 menu go to >Project >> Properties >> from right tab select Reference >> click Add button >> click .NET tab >> select the System.Data.DataSetExtensions reference >> done!

Thank you Jon Skeet.